# Problem with positional arguments and functions

Tags: python, scipy

I'm using `scipy.odr` to analyze three data sets, and I'm completely at a loss for how to debug this particular issue. When I run this, it tells me that my function `*thin_lens1()*` takes one positional argument, but that two were given. I've tried a bunch of rearrangements, and I still have no idea what I've done wrong, since the only argument that `*thin_lens1()*` takes is `p1`. Any help someone might be able to provide would be greatly appreciated, as I'm completely stuck here.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.odr, scipy.special, scipy.stats


#importing data & defining focus length constants

p1,q1,up1,uq1,p2,q2,up2,uq2,p3,q3,up3,uq3 = 
np.loadtxt('lenses_data_processed.txt', 
                                     comments='#', unpack=True, 
usecols = range(0,12))

f1 = 158.695


#defining thin lens equation

def thin_lens1(p1):
    return (p1-f1)/(p1*f1)

#parameter guesses
p_guess = [1, 2]

#applying ODR
fit = scipy.odr.Model(thin_lens1)
mydata= odr.RealData(p1, q1, sx=up1, sy=uq1)
myodr = odr.ODR(mydata, fit, beta0 = p_guess, maxit=500)
myoutput = myodr.run()
myoutput.pprint()
```

Comment: What is type of p1?  Check with type(p1).

Comment: The first argument of `scipy.odr.Model()` has to be a two argument function.

Comment: What is type of p1?

Comment: type(p1) is a numpy.ndarray.

Comment: I also tried converting p1 from a numpy array to a regular list, but still got the same error.

Comment: Take another look at the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/odr.html); you might be misunderstanding how the `odr` code works.  In the example in the "Basic Usage" section of that link (and in the [documentation of `Model`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.odr.Model.html)), you'll see that the model function (i.e. `f` in the example, `thin_lens1` in your code) must accept two arguments: the parameters of the model, and an array of `x` values.  Given those values, it must return the `y` values of the function.